# How to send count of Error Logs to zabbix using Logstash output?

Tags: logstash, zabbix

I am new to Logstash. Currently I have a logstash.conf file that sends the Error logs to the zabbix item.
I have applied a custom grok filter to look for ERROR|Error|error keyword and based on that redirects the output to zabbix item.
However, I want logstash to send an incremental counter whenever the filter result evaluates to true instead of simply sending the corresponding Log.
How can I achieve that ?

Here is the snippet of the log file I am using.

```
 input {
        file {
            path => "/root/sample.log"
            type => "string"
        }
    }
    # The filter part of this file is commented out to indicate that it is
    # optional.
    filter {
            mutate {
                     add_field => { "[@metadata][error]" => "error" }
                     add_field => { "[@metadata][counter]" => "1" }
                     add_field => { "myhost" => "logstash" }

                    }
    if "grokked" not in [tags] {

     grok {
         patterns_dir => ["/root/logstash-5.5.0/pattern"]
         match => { "message" => "%{ERROR:log_level}" }
         add_tag => ["ERROR", "grokked"]
         }
    }
   }
    output {
            stdout { codec => rubydebug }

            if "ERROR" in [tags]{
                     zabbix
                     {
                      zabbix_server_host => "192.168.56.102"
                      zabbix_host => "myhost"
                      zabbix_key => "[@metadata][error]"
                      #zabbix_value => "[@metadata][counter]"
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With the [ruby filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html):

```
ruby {
    code => 'event.set("error_count", event.get("message").scan(/Error/i).length)'
}
```

That way you'll have a field called error_count with the number of time `error` (case-insensitive) appeared in `message`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it, finally :

```
input {                                         
    file {                                          
        path => "/root/sample.log"                                          
    type => "string"                                        
    }                                           
}                                           
filter {                                            

  if "grokked" not in [tags]                                            
    {                                       

    grok {                                      
            patterns_dir => ["/root/logstash-5.5.0/pattern"]                                    
        match => { "message" => "%{ERROR:log_level}" }                                  
            add_tag => ["ERROR", "grokked"]                                 
        add_field => { "[@metadata][myhost]" => "logstash" }                                    
                add_field => { "[@metadata][error]" => "error" }                                        
        add_field => { "zabbix_message" => "The following has been detected in code:: %{message}"}                                  
               }                                        
    }                                       

if "ERROR" in [tags]{                                           
        metrics {                                           
            meter => "error"                                            
            add_tag => "metric"                                         
        add_field => { "[@metadata][myhost]" => "logstash" }                                        
        add_field => { "[@metadata][error]" => "error" }                                        
        flush_interval => 30                                        
        #clear_interval => 60                                       
        add_field => { "zabbix_message" => "The current Error count is: %{[error][count]}" }                                        
        }                                           
    }                                           
}                                           
output                                          
{                                               
    #stdout { codec => rubydebug }                                      

    if "metric" in [tags]{                                      
         zabbix                                 
          {                                 
          zabbix_server_host => "192.168.56.102"                                    
          zabbix_key => "[@metadata][error]"                                    
          zabbix_host => "[@metadata][myhost]"                                  
          zabbix_value => "zabbix_message"                                  
        }                                   
    }                                       

    if "ERROR" in [tags]{                                       
                 zabbix                                         
                  {                                         
                  zabbix_server_host => "192.168.56.102"                                            
                  zabbix_key => "[@metadata][error]"                                            
                  zabbix_host => "[@metadata][myhost]"                                          
                  zabbix_value => "zabbix_message"                                          
                }                                           


    }                                       
}
```

I also created a custom pattern file to match for patterns:
 /root/logstash-5.5.0/pattern

The content of the pattern files were:

ERROR (ERROR|error|Error)